# What is a 6210 and 4354 error mean?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, com-interop, installshield-le

http://s4.postimg.org/bkprrelpp/6210.gif

Can someone explain this to me? I set my `MCMS.Primary output` as instructed by this page.

http://mdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19889/~/using-visual-studio-2013-professional-to-build-a-microsoft-visual-basic

I set the registration type to `Extract COM information`, the Scan At Build to `Dependencies and Properties`, and checked the `COM Interop`. But I'm getting an error and a warning after trying to build the project. I tried the help page that pops out after clicking the error message. But I can't find the components view it was referring to. What I want to know is how much important this COM Interop is. And also why sometimes when I build the project the error does not appear. But mostly it does.

One suggestion of that help page told me to register the item mentioned in the error message. An .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

COM extraction is useful for turning self-registration routines into Windows Installer table data. COM Interop is the equivalent for registering managed assemblies for use via COM Interop. In both cases, the resulting registry keys are used to allow other DLLs to instantiate your COM server.

So the fundamental question you have to answer here is whether `MCMS.exe` is a COM server and registers any such data. If it is and does, then something is wrong with the extraction, and this is a problem. However if `MCMS.exe` is not a COM server, or does not actually register any relevant COM data, you may need to disable COM extraction.

Comment: Is it safe to say that if I can make an installer and run it with theoretically no problems, that it is NOT a COM Server? Are there any conclusive way to check if an object is a COM Server?

Comment: I'm not certain if it's possible to prove a negative here. There are signs you can look for to indicate a positive, especially in a DLL (various exports like DllRegisterServer) or a managed assembly (attributes like ComVisible). But it's probably more important to know whether your users or other parts of your app expect the file to be registered than merely whether it can be.

Comment: I see. Well, it looks like I still have a lot to do before everything makes sense. Thank you for taking the time to answer.